# angular-google-map in hidden div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

Initially angular google map is defined in hidden div.When I click on button, maps shows top left side only(1/4th of the map) in div.I am using this code-

```
<div id="angular-google-map-container" class="col-sm-12 view-padding">
   <ui-gmap-google-map center="mapView.center" zoom="mapView.zoom" draggable="true" dragging="mapView.dragging">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="places | studiofilter : multipleDemo.activity : multipleDemo.location : multipleDemo.studio" coords="'coords'" events="cityMarkerEvents">
             <ui-gmap-windows show="'places.show'" >
                   <div > Map</div>                
             </ui-gmap-windows>
         </ui-gmap-markers>
```

This question has been asked already in stackoverflow but all are related to google map api.How can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('gMapCtrl', ['$scope','uiGmapIsReady', function($scope, IsReady){
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
$scope.displayed = false;
$scope.showMap = function(){
    $scope.displayed = true;
    IsReady.promise().then(function (maps) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(maps[0].map, 'resize');
    });
}
}]);
```

Comment: Your answer could use more content to describe why it's the right answer, what the answer actually does, etc.